# Calculate $\beta$ and the expected value of $X$ for that value of $\beta$.

Tags: probability

I have the probability density function $f(x) = \beta(x + 3), 0 < x < 1$.

I am trying to find $\beta$ and $E[X]$ for that value of $\beta$.

I know that the probability density function is $P(a \le X \le b) = \int^b_a f(x) dx$. I used this fact to calculate $\int_0^1 \beta (x + 3) dx = \beta \dfrac{7}{2}$. And since the integral of a probability density function over an interval must be $= 1$, I came to the conclusion that $\beta = \dfrac{2}{7}$.

However, I am unsure of how to calculate the expected value.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please be so kind as to check my solution for $\beta$ and demonstrate how to calculate the expected value for this value of $\beta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\beta$ calculation looks good ...
$$E[X] = \int_0^1xf(x)dx = \frac 27\int_0^1x(x+3)dx$$

Comment: Great, I understand now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx=1 \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{1} \beta(x+3)dx=1 \Rightarrow \beta(\frac{x^2}{2}+3x)|_{0}^{1}=1 \Rightarrow \beta=\frac{2}{7} $$
Now for calculating E(x) :
$$\int_{0}^{1} xf(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2}{7}x(x+3)dx=\frac{2}{7}(\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{3x^2}{2})|_0^1 = \frac{11}{21} $$

Comment: I think the solution should be $\dfrac{11}{21}$ -- not $\dfrac{5}{21}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right...